# Changing price based on option and getting the size to post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I am trying to change the price based on whatever is been selected from the options. A shoe come in different sizes and each has different cost to it.I want to get the item cost and the size which they have selected and `POST` it to a checkout.php page. My codes below is in a `form`. My question is how will i get it t Change the price based on the size the user choose and post the size and the price for that size.

so on the checkout.php page it will look something like

```
 product name: blue nike shoes
    size: **18 inch (+£40.00)**
    Unit price: £40.00
    total price: £40.00

<tr>
<td width="160">Price:</td>
<td name="price"><?php echo $row['Standard_price']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

The price is selected from a database as a standard price for the item and I want it to change(NOT ON THE DATABASE) when someone select from the options below

```
<tr>
td for="length" width="160">size*:</td>
<td>
<select name="size" class="small">
<option value="">12 size</option>
<option value="">14 size(+£30.00)</option> //if this option is selected the price will change to £30
<option value="">18 size(+£40.00)</option>//if this option is selected the price will change to £40
<option value="">20 size(+£45.00)</option>
<option value="">28 size(+£80.00)</option
</select>
```

Maybe the way i am doing it is wrong but i know it is possible to do it because i have seen it on some sites that sells items which different lengths or shapes price are different from one another.

If no one still understands me...
try buying a shoe from any site that sells and pick your size... although the price id the same for all sizes but in the cart it tells you want choose. 
In my case the size have different prices and i want it show on the cart what size you choose and also the price for that size.

Comment: You will need to use javascript if you want the price to change when the selectbox changes.

Comment: I need an example I am abit knew to this... been trying do it for some days now. I have manage to get the price to change but it doesnt POST the price or the selected size to the checkout.php

Answer (score 0):

This could help you:

```
$("select[name='size']").on("change",function(){
    if($("option:selected",$(this)).val()!="-1")
    {
        $("#spanSize").text($("option:selected",$(this)).text());
        $("#unitPrice").text($("option:selected",$(this)).val());
        $("#totalPrice").text($("option:selected",$(this)).val());
    }
    else
    {
        $("#spanSize").text("");
        $("#unitPrice").text("");
        $("#totalPrice").text("");
    }
});
```

<kbd>[SEE LIVE CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/QFaY6/)</kbd>

Comment: That looks good but i want to post it as all the code is in a form so that aint gonna work

Comment: On the checkout.php it will be like 

if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
    $pid = $_POST['pid'];
 $qty = $_POST['Qty'];
 $size= $_POST['size'];
 $price = $_POST['price'];